# Can some explain string literals to me with the provided code?

Tags: python, pycharm

What do I need to change to make this program work? I am getting:

```
line 10
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x92' in file C:/Users/RobotAdmin/PycharmProjects/untitled3/dialouge on line 10, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I have no idea what this means.

```
def main ():
    phrases = "Thank You Please Hello Hi How Old Are You What Is Your Address"**       # String literal

    print(phrases[17:22])   # This statement prints a specific segment of characters from the string literal
    name = input('What is your name? :')     # This statement prompts the user to enter their name and accepts it
    print(phrases[23:25] + " " + name)     # Retrieves from the string literal,and combines it with the name
    print(phrases[25:41])   # This Statement asks for the user’s age
    age = input('Age in Years? :')  # This statement prompts the user to enter their age and accepts the age the entered
    print(phrases[42:64])   # This segment asks What the user’s address is
    address = input("Street Address, City, State, Country") #This statement asks user to enter their address
    print (""
           "______________________________"
           "|                            |"
           "|",name,"                    |"
           "|                            |"
           "|",age,"                     |"
           "|                            |"
           "|",address,"                 |"
           "|                            |"
           "|                            |"
           "|____________________________|")
```

Comment: Did you Google the error or visit the website it told you to visit?

Comment: The right side of your output box is going to look staggered, because you aren't taking into account the lengths of `name`, `age`, or `address` when outputting spaces to justify the box. Also, why are you using a single string for `phrases` instead of a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting your error is because of the character `’` used in your `user’s` comment which is subtlety different to `user's` which is standard ASCII. So the easiest solution is to just change those two characters.

If you'd prefer to keep them, you just need to add a suitable coding to the top of your script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

To fix the script output, one solution is to use a dictionary to store your variables. This has two advantages, firstly you can easily determine the length of all of the text that was entered. Secondly it can be used with a `format` statement to substitute the placeholders in your output.

With some extra (rather weird) notation, we can get Python to automatically add enough space or underscore padding to all line up.

```
def main ():
    phrases = "Thank You Please Hello Hi How Old Are You What Is Your Address"        #**       # String literal

    details = dict()
    print(phrases[17:22])   # This statement prints a specific segment of characters from the string literal
    details['name'] = input('What is your name? :')     # This statement prompts the user to enter their name and accepts it
    print(phrases[23:25] + " " + details['name'])     # Retrieves from the string literal,and combines it with the name
    print(phrases[25:41])   # This Statement asks for the user's age
    details['age']  = input('Age in Years? :')  # This statement prompts the user to enter their age and accepts the age the entered
    print(phrases[42:64])   # This segment asks What the user's address is
    details['address'] = input("Street Address, City, State, Country") #This statement asks user to enter their address

    # Determine the length of the longest entry
    max_width = max([len(v) for v in details.values()])

    print ("""
__{0:_<{width}}__
| {0: <{width}} |
| {name:{width}} |
| {0: <{width}} |
| {age:{width}} |
| {0: <{width}} |
| {address:{width}} |
| {0: <{width}} |
| {0: <{width}} |
|_{0:_<{width}}_|""".format('', width=max_width, **details))

main()
```

This would display something like the following output:

```
_____________________________
|                           |
| Fred Flintstone           |
|                           |
| 35                        |
|                           |
| Cobblestone Lane, Bedrock |
|                           |
|                           |
|___________________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below as it is and insert it on top of the code.

```
# coding: utf8
```

**NOTE: It must be at the top.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, it would be better for readability if you broke up your phrases inside a list, instead of splicing a string.

```
phrases = ['Hello', 'Thank You', 'How old are you'] #rest of phrases    
print (phrases[0]) #prints out "Hello"
```

Secondly, I tried out the code exactly how you had posted it, but instead plugged in dummy values for name, age, and address, and the code ran with no errors (though perhaps not with the formatting that you might have desired). The Unicode character it is talking about('\x92' ) is a comma. Do you have any extraneous commas?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `\x92` is a comma?